# Simple ScriptBlock works locally but not remotely

Tags: powershell, io, powershell-4.0

I have a file which I am transfering from one computer to another using `PowerShell 4.0`. I create a read buffer, turn that into a Base64String then open a new PSSession. Finally, I call this code:

```
#Open a file stream to destination path in remote session and write buffer to file
#First save string buffer to variable so FromBase64String() parses correctly in ScriptBlock
$remoteCommand = 
"#First save string buffer to variable so FromBase64String() parses correctly below
    `$writeString = `"$stringBuffer`"
    `$writeBuffer = [Convert]::FromBase64String(`"`$writeString`")
    `$writeStream = [IO.File]::Open(`"$destPath`", `"Append`")
    `$writeStream.Write(`$writeBuffer, 0, `$writeBuffer.Length)
    `$WriteStream.Close()
"
Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock{ Invoke-Expression $args[0] } -ArgumentList $remoteCommand -Session $remoteSession
```

I have tried running

```
Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock{ Invoke-Expression $args[0] } -ArgumentList $remoteCommand
```

Which runs fine, creating a file and writing the byte[] as expected. When I run

```
Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock{ Invoke-Expression $args[0] } -ArgumentList $remoteCommand -Session $remoteSession
```

I get the error

> Exception calling "Open" with "2" argument(s): "Could not find a part
>   of the path 'C:\Test\3.txt'."

What I expected this to do was parse the command on the remote machine, so that it creates a new file 'C:\Test\3.txt' on the remote machine and appends the byte[]. Any ideas how I could acheive this?

Comment: `Copy-Item file.txt "\\$remoteComputer\C$\Test\3.txt"`

Comment: Thanks @AnsgarWiechers, but I am copying large files across slow networks with potential problems and as far as I know, if I copy a 40 GB .zip file and a problem occurs after 90% is transferred I would have to restart the process.

Comment: Increasing the size of the transmitted data by 30% and using a PowerShell session instead of SMB doesn't solve this problem. Use [`robocopy /z`](https://technet.microsoft.com/de-de/library/cc733145%28v=ws.10%29.aspx).

Comment: Actually, it would fix the probelm as I could resume from the point of failure with a little more code. The added problem is that the destinations can be on DHCP and all I have sometimes is an IP address. I have had issues where the IP has changed when a link has been reestablished. I have extra code to handle establishing new sessions with those computers so that I can continue appending byte[] to file when the above code works.

Comment: `robocopy /z` already does all of that, but if you think you need to re-invent the wheel: be my guest.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Im missing the part where you pass the `$stringBuffer` to your scriptblock. However, first you can write a scriptblock much more easy using curly brackets. Then you could use `$using:VARIABLENAME` to pass a local script variable:

```
$remoteCommand = {
    #First save string buffer to variable so FromBase64String() parses correctly below
    $writeString = $using:stringBuffer
    $writeBuffer = [Convert]::FromBase64String($writeString)
    $writeStream = [IO.File]::Open($destPath, "Append")
    $writeStream.Write($writeBuffer, 0, $writeBuffer.Length)
    $WriteStream.Close()
}

Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock $remoteCommand -Session $remoteSession
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. That neatens up the code, thanks (+1). It doesn't, however help with the problem of the command leading to the error - Exception calling "Open" with "2" argument(s): "Could not find a part of the path 'C:\Test\3.txt', so I can't accept it as an answer.

Comment: does the path exist on the remote machine?

Comment: No. I tried creating the file on the remote machine and appending which worked. Apparently FileStream can create files, but not directories.

Comment: So all you have to do is something like `New-Item C:\Test\3.txt -ItemType File`

Comment: Yeah, when I ran it with `New-Item C:\Test\ -type directory` preceding opening the FileStream it worked fine. Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

You could write it as a function locally and then send the function to the remote computer.

```
function remoteCommand 
   {
    #First save string buffer to variable so FromBase64String() parses correctly       below
    $writeString = $using:stringBuffer
    $writeBuffer = [Convert]::FromBase64String($writeString)
    $writeStream = [IO.File]::Open($destPath, "Append")
    $writeStream.Write($writeBuffer, 0, $writeBuffer.Length)
    $WriteStream.Close()
   }

Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock ${function:remoteCommand} -Session $remoteSession
```

Comment: Would that be faster to place the Function inside the ScriptBlock command to be executed remotely on the target server?